# C Program (Prime Number in a given range)

Tags: c, primes

I have started learning C language. I wrote this program to find all prime numbers between the given range but I am unable to get the expected output.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this program please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int min, max, i, j, count = 0;
    printf("Enter Your First Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &min);
    printf("Enter Your Last Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &max);
    for(i=min; i<=max; i++) {
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            if(i % j == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==2) {
            printf("%d\t",i);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You need to reset `count` for each candidate.

Comment: In addition to what @WeatherVane said, if you know how to write functions, it's better to create an `isPrime` function.

Comment: `i%j` is true for every i and `j==1 || j==i`. You should test your program in a debugger. And when asking here, please always give everything so that others can reproduce the problem. In your case the input given is missing, the expected output and the observed output. (see [mcve])

Comment: the numbers 0 and 1 are defined as NOT prime, however, with the current code, when the value for `min` is either of those numbers 'bad' things happen.

Answer (score 2):

I just suggest getting rid of that `count` variable.

How do you know if a number N is prime? If for every `j` in the range (2 to N-1) you have `N%j != 0`.

So:

- In the inner loop, use `j` from 2 to N-1 (instead of from 1 to N as you used tio do). In fact N%1 and N%N will be 0
- The first time you find a `j` so that `N % j == 0` break. You are sure **it's not** prime
- Why incrementing `count`? For a prime number the `j` counter will be equal to `i` (because you looped until `j<i`, and the last `j++` made `j`
  equal to `i`). So just check for `j == i` and print the prime number `i`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int min, max, i, j, count = 0;
    printf("Enter Your First Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &min);
    printf("Enter Your Last Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &max);

    for(i=min; i<=max; i++)
    {
        // Was for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        for(j=2; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                //Was count++;
                break;
            }
        }

        //Was if(count==2)
        if(j == i)
        {
            printf("%d\t",i);
        }
    }
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to search up to `N - 1`; up to and including `ceil(sqrt(max))` is sufficient. If `i` is composite, then one factor is not larger than √N and the other is not smaller than √N). After you've checked for 'divisible by 2', you could check only the odd numbers. If you check for 'divisible by 3' outside the loop, then all bigger primes have the form 6K±1 for an integer `K` starting at `K` equal to 1. Limiting the search range gives a radical speedup even when `max` is just in the thousands, let alone much bigger.  Using 'odds only' does 1/2 the work; using 6K±1 does 1/3.

Comment: If the range to be searched is big enough (range or maximum value large enough), building a Sieve of Eratosthenes (or even more advanced techniques) for the primes up to the square root of the maximum and then testing only the 'known to be prime' possible factors can be beneficial.

Comment: @johnatanleffler I admit I just focused on OP's code, and on what I considered the minimum correction to make it working instead of worrying about efficiency. I was aware of the odd-numbers tecnique, of the sqrt(N) limit and of sieve of erathostenes algorithm (but not of the 6k±1 criteria. That's great!). Ack this comment and my answer will disappear (I was already going to do it without your comments)

Comment: No need to remove it unless you want to. It’s fine as a minimal set of changes to get the OP going.  And comments are ephemeral; don’t change what you’d do simply because I comment.  If there was a substantive technical error, then I prefer you to take note, but for comments providing auxilliary information like this, do as you would anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    printf( "Enter the range of numbers (two unsigned integer numbers): " );

    unsigned int first = 0, last = 0;

    scanf( "%u %u", &first, &last );

    if ( last < first )
    {
        unsigned int tmp = first;
        first = last;
        last = tmp;
    }

    do
    {
        int prime = first % 2 == 0 ? first == 2 : first != 1;

        for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= first / i; i += 2 )
        {
            prime = first % i != 0;
        }

        if ( prime ) printf( "%u ", first ); 
    } while ( first++ != last );

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the range of numbers (two unsigned integer numbers): 0 100
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

As for your program then you need re-initialize the variable count before the inner loop

```
for(i=min; i<=max; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        if(i % j == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

And the inner loop is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Need to reset the value of `count`. It starts at `count=0`, then for any inputs, the loops will count up. The For each outer loop index, it will go like this:

- `1` (`1%1=0` --> `count++`, `count = 1`)
- `2` (`2%1=0` --> `count++`, and `2%2=0` --> `count++`, `count = 3`)
- `3` (`3%1=0` --> `count++`, and `3%3=0` --> `count++`, `count = 5`)

etc... until `max` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple isprime function to check whether a number is prime or not and then call the function for the given interval.
To find whether a number is prime or not , we can use a simple primality test to check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


bool isprime(int n)
{
     if(n <= 1) return false;
     if(n <= 3) return true;

     if(n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false;

     for(int i = 5;i*i <= n;i += 6)
     {
        if(n%i == 0 || n%(i + 2) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
 }



int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter the first number :");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the second number :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(int i = a;i <= b;i++)
    {
       if(isprime(i)) printf("%d ",i);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is a simple change you should do:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int min, max, i, j, count;
    printf("Enter Your First Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &min);
    printf("Enter Your Last Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &max);
    for(i=min; i<=max; i++)
    {
        count=1;
        for(j=2; j<=i; j++) 
        {
            if(i % j == 0) {
            count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==2) {
            printf("%d\t",i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes your answer unique? There are already better answers in all aspects: minimal change to make it work, possible improvements, and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be a bit late, but since it's the same issue, i'll write it here in case it helps someone else coming to this thread in the future.

My code is written from the POV of a beginner (No complex functions or data types are used) as this is a code that mostly they will get stuck on.

Working:

1. User inputs the range.
2. Using the `for` loop, each number in the range is sent to the `isprime` function which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` after checking the condition for being a prime number.
3. if `TRUE` : program prints the number.
4. if `FALSE` : program skips the number using `continue` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int isprime(int num);

int main() {
    int min, max;
    printf("Input the low number: ");
    scanf("%d", &min);
    printf("Input the high number: ");
    scanf("%d", &max);
    
    for(int i = min; i<=max; i++) {
        if(isprime(i) == 1) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
        else if(isprime(i) == 0){
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int isprime(int num) {
     int count = 0;
    for(int i=2; i<=(num/2); i++) {
        if(num % i == 0 ) {
            count ++;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    if(count>0){
            return 0;
        }
        else if (count == 0){
            return 1;
        }
}
```